# Copy and paste Excel data to an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to copy and paste data (B3 to H17) into the body of a prebuilt email with Excel.

I prefer not activating references because it will be used by other people who have access to the sheet.

```vb
Sub Email_From_Excel_Basic()
    
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
    
    Set emailApplication = Create object ("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Now we build the email.
    emailItem.to = "to emails here"
    emailItem.Subject = "here is the subject"
    emailItem.Body = "need the cells pasted here whereevwr the macro told them to copy "
    
    ' Display the Email so the user can change it as desired before sending it.
    emailItem.Display
    
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailApplication = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the required data in Excel and paste it programmatically using the Word object model. See the third case listed below.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx). If you don't want to add a reference to the Word object model you can construct the required HTML markup based on the Excel data and set up the `HTMLBody` property.
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.